# Probability mass function for discrete case

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For a discrete random variable what does the pmf mean?

Suppose we are given a pmf like this

```
f | 0   |  1  | 2
----------------
  | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.2
```

Now these values <=1 and >=0 but that doesn't mean they are probability (just considering the analogy from pdf case of continuous random variable). Please let me know if I am thinking it right.

The probabilities would be the CDF

```
F |  0 | 1    | 2
----------------
  |  0.5| 0.8 | 1
```

80% chance of observing a value <=1 and 100% chance of observing a value <=2

Comment: For the case of pmf, they indeed do mean probabilities. So if the given pmf is of a random variable $X$, it implies that $\Pr(X = 0) = 0.5$, $\Pr(X = 1) = 0.3$ and $\Pr(X = 2) = 0.2$.

Comment: How come? @sudeep5221 Thats exactly opposite of what I said.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your confusion exactly but I what I stated in the previous comment is the definition of a pmf.

Comment: @sudeep5221 I see..sorry. It's completely different from pdf of continuous case..that's why this confusion

Comment: @sudeep5221 How do you explain $P(X=x)=0$ for continuous case?

Comment: @mathuser001 That is a fundamental difference between continuous and discrete random variables. It can't be explained well without a good background in measure theory, so for now I'd advise you accept that continuous variables take values over intervals, as opposed to exact points.

Comment: An intuitive explanation is as follows. Think of pdf as a stretched elastic sheet. So if you try to obtain the "mass" of the sheet at a particular point (say by a needle), what you would obtain is nothing. However, for discrete case, think of it like small elastic balls at certain points. So when you try to get the mass at that point, you end up picking a ball with a certain non-zero mass. This explanation by no means is a rigorous one but might help you get a better idea of what the difference can be. As @Math1000 mentioned, a rigorous explanation isn't possible without knowing measure theory

Comment: @Math1000 Sad that I don't know enough math to understand basic things. People like me should stop to exist. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Makes sense....Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @mathuser001 You would need to study mathematics at a graduate level (for example, as part of a PhD program), to really understand this matter. I wouldn't say it's "basic" by any means.